# Problemas con function Date() al convertir String a Date

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema con la funcion date() de javascript lo que quiero es convertir de un string a una fecha pero convierte la fecha menos 1 dia.

```
function myFunction() {
var d = new Date('2018-02-28');
var n = d.toString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

lo que muestra es:

```
Tue Feb 27 2018 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)
```

Espero me puedan ayudar necesito ese formato, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

como comenta **jorge marquez** es necesario añadir algo más, aunque algo curioso es que no necesariamente es la hora con minutos y segundos. También funciona agregando simplemente un espacio después del día, en tu caso:

```js
var d = new Date('2018-02-28 ');  // Fijese que hay un espacio despues del 28
```

También puedes por claridad colocar "00:00", hasta funciona colocando un espacio y simples dos puntos

```js
var d = new Date('2018-02-28 :');
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, funciono

Answer (score 4):

Realmente no es *menos un día*, sino menos 4 horas: La clase Date cuando no se le pasa la hora, asume que la hora es 00:00:00 pero en el uso horario `GMT 0000`, por lo que en tu máquina, que tiene la hora `GMT-0400`, aparece con 4 horas menos.

Mi consejo es usar la librería moment.js para simplificar, pero otra solución es añadir el tiempo: `'2018-02-28 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 2):

la razón por que la fecha te sale así es por que necesitas poner toda la fecha con horas minutos y segundos para que te la convierta; así : 2018-02-28 00:00:00

entonces tu código quedaría así

```
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date('2018-02-28 00:00:00');
  var n = d.toString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

saludos